# How to customise React AsyncSelect style

Tags: css, reactjs, select, react-component

I am trying to customise the style of AsyncSelect component, but seems not able to do it.

```
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';
<AsyncSelect
  classNamePrefix='testSelect'
  ......
/>
```

scss file:
Both ways are not working

```
.testSelect__menu {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px -5px #ccc, -5px 5px 15px -5px #ccc !important;
  background-color: black !important;
  z-index: 10 !important;
}
```

```
.testSelect {
  &__menu {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px -5px #ccc, -5px 5px 15px -5px #ccc !important;
    background-color: black !important;
    z-index: 10 !important;
  }
}
```

Anyone knows how to solve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-async-forked-tq6ruw?file=/src/index.js) & the css class `testSelect__menu` is applied to the inner elements. Which results in the output -

[image]

Maybe you want to look into if scss is configured correctly or not?